# Most efficient way to write system files in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, system, root

I'm writing an app that changes the cpu governor similar to setCpu.

The problem im having is sometimes when writing the governor file (a system file), i get an IOException (bad file number) and it seems to happen randomly.

I'm requesting root in my onCreate method and keeping the process as a field:

```
private Process suProcess;

public void onCreate(Bundle ...) {
    ...    
    suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    ...
```

and when i need to write a system file this is my code:

```
try {
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    out.writeBytes("echo " + FILE_CONTENTS + " > " + SYSTEM_FILE);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is this the proper way to handle root permissions? And why am i getting the IOException randomly? (sometimes it works sometimes not)

Answer (score 0):

Not alot of interest in this question apparently but heres my solution.

Call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

in onCreate to ensure the user doesn't have to deal with the SU dialog during use.

Then when writing system files create another SU process (application should already have su permission)

```
try {
    Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    out.writeBytes("echo " + FILE_CONTENTS + " > " + SYSTEM_FILE);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```